# run yarn to build a laravel app from another laravel app in the same server

Tags: laravel, yarnpkg

I m trying to run yarn on an app B when I click a button in the laravel app A.
This yarn will call webpack to copy some folder then build a store.

I tried to cd to app B then exec() the command yarn but it doesnt work. I can do it only manually in the app B folder.

My 2 apps are running in a virtual machine vagrant box

Comment: Exec provides a return code and stores output, have you captured either?  "Doesn't work" isn't a very good description of the problem.

Comment: yarn run v1.12.3 $ npm run development --store=mbmb > @ development /home/vagrant/code/front-end > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: Error Output: = npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! path sh npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn sh npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! logs/2debug.log error Command failed with exit code 1.